# Eclipse not showing jar files in lib folder?

Tags: eclipse

I am developing a web based project but recently I am facing problem with eclipse j2ee kepler version for java 8. When I am loading the jar file to lib folder It's not loading to the lib folder and I am finding a warning which is causing a runtime exception to my project. Actually when I am adding a jar file to eclipse project using build path i am getting an error like as. Classpath entry:(File location).jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundException my result. It shows on markers in eclipse. Please help me out with this problem. Thanks

Comment: Adding JARs to an arbitrary "`lib`" folder, by itself, will do nothing - unless the `lib` folder is configured to be on the classpath.

What type of Java project is this?  Stand-alone or web application?

Eclipse Kepler is also 2 versions out-of-date, and an upgrade to Mars should probably be considered.

Comment: Is this mars will support java 8, actually I am new to this field I don't know how to set classpath for lib folder. Any how I will try with mars

Comment: Upgrading to Mars itself will most likely not resolve your issue - but will have better Java 8 support than Kepler.  If you still have issues, please edit your post to include some screenshots of the error as well as your "Java Build Path" properties tabs.  Also, what type of Java project is this - stand-alone or web?

Comment: sorry I am afraid i can't upload the screen shots. Actually I am developing a standalone project just for practice but recently I am facing this problem with eclipse.